# How to send an object array using $http post in angular? http error code 500

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, http

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to send an array with two objects using $ http post ...
I already tried to convert the array using angular.toJson,
I also tried to convert using JSON.stringify, I even tried using the two options and nothing works ... all my attempts result in an error of http code 500.

I do not know what to do anymore

I have the object 'ordemServico' that only has simple data all as string and when I only pass it in the post everything works:

```
                $http({
                method: metodo,
                url: urlBase + 'ordensServico/',
                data: self.ordemServico
            }).then(function sucessCallback(response) {
               self.atualizarTabela();
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                self.ocorreuErro();
            });
```

however, I need to send this object and a second object containing some files.

I'm trying to test just by passing the same object twice in an array, but it does not work at all:

```
$scope.final = new Object();
$scope.final={'ordemServico': self.ordemServico, 'imagens': self.ordemServico};
           $http({
                method: metodo,
                url: urlBase + 'ordensServico/',
                data: $scope.final
            }).then(function sucessCallback(response) {
               self.atualizarTabela();
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                self.ocorreuErro();
            });
```

Comment: Do you have any more info on that 500 error? It's possible that your data is being sent correctly but the server breaks.

Comment: May be try to send  `contentType: "application/json"` in $http ; 
or @NilesTanner might be correct, issue with your backend code

Comment: the error must be in your backend... your $scope.final look good. perhaps 'ordemServico' and 'imagens' are the same.

Comment: can you provide your server error logs and the output of the http response ?

Comment: @RahulNaik that is the default `$http` content-type. There is no need to set it. Also, that is **not** how you set the header in AngularJS